# SDE GDB Versioning - reconcile and post from DEFAULT to Child

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I am relatively new to versioning and think I have made a mistake in my workflow.

I am using a SDE geodatabase, with a DEFAULT and 'Field Editing' child version in ArcGIS 10.3.

I received a lot of new data, so populated the DEFAULT version using the Object Loader tool - this works fine.  However, I am now setting up a MXD which will be used to publish a map service (surfaced on Collector), and want to use the Field Editing version - but the changes I made are obviously not shown in this version.  I don't seem to be able to reconcile and post the changes to the child version.

Is there a way I can do this automatically? Or is the best method to copy the features to the child version, delete those in the Default, and then post and reconcile the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reconcile and Post works from child version to parent version. Not reversely.**

So the correct way is to load your data to child version ("Field Editing") and then reconcile/post to default.

I am not sure how Object Loader works, but if you do this in MXD you firstly need to change DEFAULT version of your layer to "Field Editing". To do so:

In Table of content click on second icon "List by source" then right click on database node (with DEFAULT version) and click Change Version... and pick your field editing version. After you change the version, load data to this version.

If you wish to do this in ArcCatalog:
Right click on database connection select *Geodatabase connection properties* and then change default version to field editing version. After that right click on feature class and select load...

Comment: Makak - that makes sense, I will do that.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I loaded the data into the Field Editing version, which worked fine.  I reconciled and posted, but this duplicated the data in both versions.  So I deleted the duplicates in the Field Editing version, and deleted all in the DEFAULT version.  But when I reconcile, it then removes everything from the Field Editing version and I'm left with nothing.  I stopped editing without saving to retain the data, and now backed it up.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JenB Sorry I was few days offline. I meant my answer as "how it should be done properly". So to fix your issue I will start from scratch. Delete all from default and from your editing version. I am not completely aware of your situation, but if it is possible, delete "field editing" version. Unregister dataset as versioned. Register dataset as versioned again, create editing version and do your edits in a way I described in my answer. It should work...

Comment: thank you for your reply, I appreciate your help.  I essentially did what you said - delete the data from the default and editing version, unregister database as versioned, loading data into it, and register dataset as versioned again, reconciled and posted.  Works great.  Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: you are welcome, I am glad it worked...